# Alacarte: copy applications to another menu

Tags: alacarte

I've create a new menu, named "favorite" and I want to copy my favorite programs into this favorite menu. How can I do that?
Is there a manual or help for Alacarte?

Comment: Copy the .desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/` into `~/.local/share/applications` and rename them  and then edit them to include your menu (there is an option in each file to have it point to a submenu)

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand - you use classic desktop (such as GNOME FlashBack or MATE DE).

- Alacarte does not allow to do this simply.
- But Mozo (its fork on MATE DE) has this functionality (install it with `sudo apt-get install mozo`). The following steps will help:

  1. start Mozo (on MATE DE by right-clicking on *Applications* menu or *System->Preferences->Look and Feel->Main Menu*);
  2. create new menu name `favorite` with *New Menu* button;
  3. drag-and-drop application icon between existing *Menu* "directory" and your new `favorite` menu.

Your idea works great on MATE DE.